# Enumeration, making it available without instantiation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums, global

I have an enumeration inside a class:

```
Public Class objConjuntosDeAvaliacoes    
    Const conjuntoTipoComparacao As String = "cmp"
    Const conjuntoTipoEvolucao As String = "evp"

    Function removeDoConjunto(ByVal ansSerie As Integer, 
                              ByVal ansAvaliacao As Integer) As Integer
```

I would like this enumeration to be available in all code files, without having to instantiate the class.

How do you do that?

Comment: I don't see an `Enum`, only two constants and a `Function` prototype...

Comment: Those are not enumerations, those are constants... two different things

Comment: What enumeration?  The two const values?  If so, make them static (keyword `shared` in VB I think)

Answer (score 0):

[`Enum` Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyxe49xw.aspx):

```
Public Class objConjuntosDeAvaliacoes
    .....  
    'enums
    Public Enum YourEnums
        conjuntoTipoComparacao = 1
        conjuntoTipoEvolucao = 2
    End Enum

    'public constants
    Public Const conjuntoTipoComparacao As String = "cmp"
    Public Const conjuntoTipoEvolucao As String = "evp"
    .....
.....
```

Comment: I assume he actually wants something like `Public Const conjuntoTipoComparacao As YourEnums = YourEnums.cmp`

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code. Anyway, what I would like to do was to use something like...
"if strClassOfCustomer is Customer.Gold then..."
without having to instantiate anything...